# External IP Address in Swift 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ip

I have checked almost all Stackoverflow answers and follow them all. But I every time get the **Default Gateway IP** instead of **External IP**

**I don't want to use ThirdParty APIs who list back IP Address in Response.** I want to **use only Swift or Objective-C code** to retrieve **External IP**.

```
Default Gateway IP => 100.45.150.231
External IP        => 106.72.187.241
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your device is behind a NAT gateway, you need to ask a host on the Internet what IP address it sees for you.  The device itself doesn't know as the NAT is transparent.

Comment: I need External IP using iOS System Native code only. I don't want to call ThirdParty Web API. And this another question is only showing up the results of ThirdParty Web API. So please check and remove from Duplicate.

Comment: It isn’t possible to do that. The iOS device doesn’t know anything about the external IP address. Only devices outside the NAT gateway can see the external address

Comment: Oh Ok, I got your point. But I have a doubt regarding below point.
Verizone, AT&T, Sprint, T-Mobile assign private IP Addresses to each devices. So how do they manage to do this?

Comment: Because they use Network Address Translation (NAT) to rewrite the packet headers as they traverse their network boundary

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. :)